# Bokeh: chart from pandas dataframe won't update on trigger

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh, interaction

I have got a pandas dataframe whose columns I want to show as lines in a plot using a Bokeh server. Additionally, I would like to have a slider for shifting one of the lines against the other.

My problem is the update functionality when the slider value changes. I have tried the code from the sliders-example of bokeh, but it does not work.

Here is an example

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.io import vform
from bokeh.plotting import Figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, ColumnDataSource, Slider

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[3,4,5]])
df = df.transpose()
myindex = list(df.index.values)
mysource = ColumnDataSource(df)

plot = Figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)

for i in range(len(mysource.column_names) - 1):
    name = mysource.column_names[i]    
    plot.line(x = myindex, y = str(name), source = mysource)

offset = Slider(title="offset", value=0.0, start=-1.0, end=1.0, step=1)

def update_data(attrname, old, new):
    # Get the current slider values
    a = offset.value

    temp = df[1].shift(a)
    #to finish#

offset.on_change('value', update_data)

layout = vform(offset, plot)

show(layout)
```

Inside the `update_data`-function I have to update `mysource`, but I cannot figure out how to do that. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try... change `a=offset.value` to `a=cb_obj.get('value')`

Then put `source.trigger('change')` after you do whatever it is you are trying to do in that `update_data` function instead of `offset.on_change('value', update_data)`.

Also change `offset = Slider(title="offset", value=0.0, start=-1.0, end=1.0, step=1, callback=CustomJS.from_py_func(offset))`

Note this format I'm using works with `flexx` installed.  https://github.com/zoofio/flexx if you have Python 3.5 you'll have to download the zip file, extract, and type `python setup.py install` as it isn't posted yet compiled for this version...