# Simple Bokeh app: Chart does not update as expected

Tags: python, bokeh

So I have been trying to build a little something from the bokeh example there:

https://demo.bokeh.org/weather.

My dataset is really similar and this should be very straight forward, yet I have a problem that I cannot explain.

```
import os , pickle
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import row, column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Select
from bokeh.plotting import figure


base_path = '/Users/xxxxxx/Desktop/data/'
domain = 'IEM_Domain'
metric = 'total_area_burned'

def get_dataset(dic , selection , scenario):
    def _get_mean(thing):
        _df = pd.DataFrame(thing)
        _df = _df.mean(axis = 1).cumsum(axis=0)
        return _df

    data = { model : _get_mean( dic[model] ) for model in dic.keys() if all([scenario in model , selection in model])}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)

    return ColumnDataSource(data=df)

def make_plot(source, title):
    plot = figure(x_axis_type="datetime", plot_width=800, tools="")
    plot.title.text = title

    for _df in source :
        for col in _df.to_df().columns :
            if 'index' not in col :
                plot.line( _df.to_df()['index'] , _df.to_df()[col] , source = _df)
            else : pass

    # fixed attributes
    plot.xaxis.axis_label = 'Year'
    plot.yaxis.axis_label = "Area burned (km)"
    plot.axis.axis_label_text_font_style = "bold"

    return plot

def update_plot(attrname, old, new):
    rcp45 = rcp45_select.value
    rcp85 = rcp85_select.value

    src45 = get_dataset(dic , rcp45 , 'rcp45')
    src85 = get_dataset(dic , rcp85 , 'rcp85')

    source45.data = src45.data
    source85.data = src85.data


rcp45 = 'CCSM4_rcp45'
rcp85 = 'CCSM4_rcp85'

dic = pickle.load(open(os.path.join(base_path , "_".join([domain , metric ]) + '.p'), 'rb'),encoding='latin1')

rcp45_models = [ i for i in dic.keys() if 'rcp45' in i]
rcp85_models = [ i for i in dic.keys() if 'rcp85' in i]

rcp45_select = Select(value=rcp45, title='RCP 45', options=sorted(rcp45_models))
rcp85_select = Select(value=rcp85, title='RCP 85', options=sorted(rcp85_models))

source45 = get_dataset(dic , rcp45 , 'rcp45')
source85 = get_dataset(dic , rcp85 ,'rcp85')
print(source45.data)
plot = make_plot([source45 , source85], "Total area burned ")

rcp45_select.on_change('value', update_plot)
rcp85_select.on_change('value', update_plot)

controls = column(rcp45_select, rcp85_select)

curdoc().add_root(row(plot, controls))
curdoc().title = "Total Area burned"
```

Everything runs find until I try to change the value in the dropdown, I can see that the function `update_plot()` is doing the job, updating the data when the dropdown is used. But for some reason the plot doesn't change , the example works fine though. I have been digging everywhere in the code but can't seem to find what I am doing wrong.

I have tried to simplify the make_plot() to see if it could come from there but that didn't change anything so I am out of ideas.

I found that but couldn't apply it : [Bokeh: chart from pandas dataframe won't update on trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36497285/bokeh-chart-from-pandas-dataframe-wont-update-on-trigger)

**Edit after first answer**

I tried to get ride of the columndatasource and replaced it by a traditionnal dictionnary but still run into the same issue. 
Here is the updated code :

```
import os , pickle
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import row, column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Select
from bokeh.plotting import figure


base_path = '/Users/julienschroder/Desktop/data/'
domain = 'IEM_Domain'
metric = 'total_area_burned'
scenarios = ['rcp45','rcp85']


def get_dataset(dic ,selection , scenario = scenarios):
    #function taking the raw source as dic and a selection of models, it return a dictionnary 
    # like this {scenario : pd.Dataframe(models)} that way i can plot each scenario on their own

    def _get_mean_cumsum(df ,name):
        #Extract, average and cumsum the raw data to a dataframe
        _df = pd.DataFrame(df)
        _df = _df.mean(axis = 1).cumsum(axis=0)
        _df = _df.to_frame(name=name)
        return _df

    #Just one model at a time for now but hoping to get multilines and so multi models in the future
    data = { scenario : pd.concat([_get_mean_cumsum(dic[model] , model) for model in selection if scenario in model ] ,axis=1)  for scenario in scenarios }

    return data

def make_plot(source, title):
    plot = figure(x_axis_type="datetime", plot_width=800, tools="")
    plot.title.text = title
    #for now it will just deal with one model at a time but in the future I hope to have some multiline plotting hence the for loops
    for col in source['rcp45']:
        plot.line(source['rcp45'].index,source['rcp45'][col] )

    for col in source['rcp85']:
        plot.line(source['rcp85'].index , source['rcp85'][col])

    # fixed attributes
    plot.xaxis.axis_label = 'Year'
    plot.yaxis.axis_label = "Area burned (km)"
    plot.axis.axis_label_text_font_style = "bold"

    return plot

def update_plot(attrname, old, new):
    rcp45 = rcp45_select.value
    rcp85 = rcp85_select.value

    source = get_dataset(dic,[rcp45 ,rcp85])

    #check to see if source gets updated
    print(source) # <- gets updated properly after dropdown action

rcp45 = 'CCSM4_rcp45'
rcp85 = 'CCSM4_rcp85'

# dic = pickle.load(open(os.path.join(base_path , "_".join([domain , metric ]) + '.p'), 'rb'),encoding='latin1')

dic = pickle.load(open('IEM_Domain_total_area_burned.p', 'rb'),encoding='latin1') #data available there : https://github.com/julienschroder/Bokeh_app/tree/master/1

rcp45_models = [ i for i in dic.keys() if 'rcp45' in i]
rcp85_models = [ i for i in dic.keys() if 'rcp85' in i]

rcp45_select = Select(value=rcp45, title='RCP 45', options=sorted(rcp45_models))
rcp85_select = Select(value=rcp85, title='RCP 85', options=sorted(rcp85_models))

source = get_dataset(dic,[rcp45 ,rcp85])

plot = make_plot(source , "Total area burned ")

rcp45_select.on_change('value', update_plot)
rcp85_select.on_change('value', update_plot)

controls = column(rcp45_select, rcp85_select)

curdoc().add_root(row(plot, controls))
curdoc().title = "Total Area burned"
```

I get my two first lines but nothing happen when using the dropdown.
I uploaded a smaller dataset on this github page if someone wants to try out the data
https://github.com/julienschroder/Bokeh_app/tree/master/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I can't say with 100% certainty since I can't run the code without the data, but I have a decent good idea what the problem might be. The `.data` attribute one `ColumnDataSource` is not actually a simple Python dictionary:

```
In [4]: s = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(a=[1,2], b=[3,4]))

In [5]: type(s.data)
Out[5]: bokeh.core.property.containers.PropertyValueDict
```

It's actually a specially wrapped dictionary that can automatically emit event notifications when its contents are changed. This is part of the machinery that let's Bokeh respond and update things automatically in such a handy way. I'm guessing that setting the `.data` of one source by using the `.data` of *another source* is what is somehow causing the problem. I'm hypothesizing that setting `.data` with something besides a real Python dicts prevents the event handlers not getting wired up correctly.

So, a suggestion for an immediate-term workaround: Don't construct a `ColumnDataSource` in `get_dataset`. Only construct and return a plain Python dictionary. It's possible that `df.to_dict` will just give you e exactly the right sort of dict. Or else you can make a dict by hand, putting in the columns you need.

And a request: It's possible that this limitation can be fixed up. Or if not, it's certainly possible that a loud warning can be made if a user does this. Please file a bug report on the [GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues) with all this information.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I tried the suggestion (or I think I did) but still don't get an updated plot. I added a link to a smaller dataset if you have time to play with it. I will keep digging.

Comment: It's not updating now because you are not updating `.data` on *any* column data source at all. You need to have code like `source.data = some_real_python_dict` where the `source` on the left is a column data source for some glyph or glyphs. The problem before was taking the `.data` off of some column data source and using it on the *right* side of the assignment. You still have to have `source.data = somethign` with a CDS on the left (thats what makes the plot update)